# Search results are not displaying

Tags: angularjs

I've built a small search app using AngularJS (1.x) and Elasticsearch. The autocomplete (Angular UI Bootstrap Typeahead) is working but for some reason the search function doesn't execute on selection and I have no idea why. I'm thinking it might have something to do with my routing (states - I'm using UI Router). I'm using Multiple Named Views because I need 2 controllers on the page.

Here is a sampling of my states:

```
.state('search', {
    url: '/search?q',
    views: {
    '': {templateUrl: '/modules/core/client/views/search.client.view.html'},
    'logo@search': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/search.logo.client.view.html',
      },
    'headersearchform@search': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/header.searchform.client.view.html',
        controller: 'SearchController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      },
    'user@search': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/header.authentication.client.view.html',
        controller: 'HeaderController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      },
    'indextabs@search': {
      templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/search.indextabs.client.view.html',
      controller: 'SearchController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
      },
```

Did I set them up wrong... or is that not even the reason why the search function doesn't execute? ... totally lost on this one.

**UPDATE 1**:
I just switched over to using controllerAs syntax so my first thought was  $scope... sorry about that.

Here is my search()

```
    //search
vm.search = function() {
  $state.go('search');
  console.log(vm.searchTerms);
  vm.currentPage = 1;
  vm.results.documents = [];
  vm.isSearching = true;
  return coreService.search(vm.searchTerms, vm.currentPage).then(function(es_return) {
    var totalItems = es_return.hits.total;
    var totalTime = es_return.took;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(es_return.hits.total / vm.itemsPerPage);
    vm.results.pagination = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      vm.results.totalItems = totalItems;
      vm.results.queryTime = totalTime;
      vm.results.pagination = coreService.formatResults(es_return.hits.hits);
      vm.results.documents = vm.results.pagination.slice(vm.currentPage, vm.itemsPerPage);
    }
        vm.noResults = true;
      }),
    function(error){
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
      vm.isSearching = false;
    },
    vm.captureQuery();
};
```

And this is the search form in the header

```
<form ng-submit="vm.search()" class="navbar-form" id="global-search-form" role="search">
```

Again have no idea why search() is NOT working/displaying. I have a *feeling* that seach() is working because my console log statements are displaying in Chrome's console but for some reason the results are NOT displaying...?

Code is working in my dev code base (basically the angular-seed project but I started to move it over to the complete MEAN stack and thought I covered all my bases... not sure what is going on

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 2**:
I'm pretty sure the results are simply NOT displaying now. I've put console.log statements in the search controller and from what I can see from those statements in the console is that search() **IS** working, its just that the results are not displaying...

I've noticed that anything below the header is not displaying data... and that is where I'm at now... I've put quite a few Multiple Named Views in this template - all having the same controller... to keep it simple.

I'm not sure why nothing below the header displays using the controllerAs syntax. I do have a simple $scope variable that is working but anything controlled by controllerAs is not?

My header looks as follows

```
    <header class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid white;">
    <div ui-view="logo@search"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 pull-left">
    <div ui-view="headersearchform@search"></div>
  </div>

  <nav role="navigation">
    <div ui-view="user@search"></div>
  </nav>
</div>
</header><!--eof header-->

<!--bof results ui section-->
```

Comment: You're using `controllerAs`, so why do you need the `$scope` for?

Comment: That title though... [Select Isn't Broken](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) :)

Comment: And where is your code of the search function?

Comment: @RonDadon just posted my search function. Any advise would be great!

Comment: @AlonEitan just switched over to using controllerAs, so $scope came to mind first... just posted more code if you have any ideas

Comment: @sp00m I've read the article and I its probably something I'm doing...  I'm looking over my code and putting log statements and testing...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if it set up correctly, could you paste the rest that utilizes this in the JS? I would suggest using Postman or Runscope to verify that API itself is not down as it is a possible issue. Also try `url: '/search?'` instead of `url: '/search?q'`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Basically what I did was I made the results page a layout page in the views object and then made a named view for the user display thats in the header. So I have a shell page and then one named view... its not exactly what I want but for now... its working. I would like multiple named views because it seems like it would be easier for updating and improving specific parts of the ui... I think as I understand UI Router more and more it'll get there.